# Locked out of local MySQL

Tags: server, software-installation, mysql, localhost

I've successfully installed MySQL a few times, and I don't know where I went wrong this time.

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
sudo mysql_install_db
```

But when using my password in

```
mysql -p
```

or

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I get an access denied error.

I tried killing the mysqld process and restarting with

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

but now I get

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

Then I tried finding the correct socket with

```
sudo find / -type s
```

But I did not find anything that looked right, so I'm stuck.

Comment: With this most recent install, have you loaded any databases yet? If not, you may want to start over. During the install you are asked for a root password and your post does not refer to this step as having taken place.

Comment: I'm fine starting over, I tried to do so, but maybe I didn't remove everything? It did ask for a root password, and I entered one, but that password didn't work (it still gave an access denied error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **Ubuntu** or **Debian**, the easiest way would be to use the defaults file as root user:

```
sudo mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

if connected just change the password for your normal account:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'tom'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('foobar');
```

or (for one user, regardless of the host):

```
UPDATE mysql.USER SET Password=PASSWORD('new-password-here') WHERE USER='user-name-here';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm in! I got "could not open default config file", but all I had to do was chown it

Comment: Or run the command as "root" user ;)